# Can I store uploaded images in a public folder on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I upload images to a public folder, not in my database. Is it okay to do this on Heroku?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not okay to do this on Heroku.

Heroku's filesystem [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you make will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

While data stored in your database won't be lost when your dyno restarts there are good reasons not to store images (or other files) directly in your database. Heroku [recommends storing uploads in something like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).